# Any callback method for migration

Tags: migrations

I have written a migration script that is working but After migrate data I need a method/way to store recent inserted id with some other relevant data in another custom database table.

Can I do with help of any hook or use any plugin. 
 This is my yml file.

```
id: order_billing_address
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags: null
migration_group: default
label: 'User profile for billing information'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: pathtocsv/order_billing_address.csv
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - profile_id
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 'customer'
  uid: uid
  profile_id: profile_id
  address/country_code: country
  address/administrative_area: state
  address/locality: locality
  address/dependent_locality: locality
  address/postal_code: postal_code
  address/sorting_code: ''
  address/address_line1: street
  address/address_line2: street2
  address/organization: company_name
  address/given_name: first_name
  address/family_name: last_name
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:profile'
migration_dependencies: {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, I will create a custom module, an event, dispatch it in a  hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert implementation and subscribe to it so that we can insert the data into different custom table.

https://x-team.com/blog/creating-and-subscribing-to-events/